# How to execute SELECT and INSERT in single query with PHP/MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, logic, identity

I have a table `user_name` with 3 fields, `id, Name, Email` (`id` is `auto_increment` field). I want to execute the following query in PHP, but its not returning any result.

```
INSERT INTO user_name (Name, Email) VALUES ('Example', 'example@xyz.com'); 
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS 'userid';
```

When I am executing the above query in PHP as below then its not returning anything.

```
$_SQL="INSERT INTO user_name (Name,Email) VALUES ('Example', 'example@xyz.com'); 
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS 'userid';";

$result_last_id = @mysql_query($_SQL);
$rs_insert = mysql_fetch_array($result_last_id);

$new_userid = $rs_insert['userid'];
```

Can anyone please tell me how to execute both queries into one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give a look to the [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) function.

```
mysql_query($insertStatementOnly);
$new_userid = mysql_insert_id();
```

Comment: "Note: The value of the MySQL SQL function LAST_INSERT_ID() always contains the most recently generated AUTO_INCREMENT value, and is not reset between queries. " this is written in the link what you have given me. Still is it OK to use mysql_insert_id() ?

Comment: Yes, just make sure to call it immediately after the insert query is executed.

Comment: This really is the best answer, and only way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

It appears you don't need to execute multiple queries, but I included how to do it below. What you want is the last inserted id, which you get from [`mysql_insert_id`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php).

#### To execute multiple queries

From comments on documentation of [`mysql_query`](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> The documentation claims that "multiple queries are not supported".
>
> However, multiple queries seem to be supported. You just have to pass flag 65536 as mysql_connect's 5 parameter (client_flags). This value is defined in /usr/include/mysql/mysql_com.h:
> `#define CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS (1UL << 16) /* Enable/disable multi-stmt support */`
>
> Executed with multiple queries at once, the mysql_query function will return a result only for the first query. The other queries will be executed as well, but you won't have a result for them.

Alternatively, have a look at the `mysqli` library, which has a [`multi_query` method](https://www.php.net/mysqli.multi-query).

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer really: You just can't do it.

http://php.net/mysql_query

Answer (score 1):

May I also suggest you avoid the error-suppression operator '@' in mysql_query as you may not be made aware of any mysql errors. At the very least do

```
mysql_query($sql) or die("error: " . mysql_error()) ;
```

Comment: Very bad idea on production website. MySQL errors can contain some sensitive data. The best solution is to log em.

Comment: Definitely agree, which is why I said "at the very least". I didn't want to go off topic by expanding on how to handle database errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Zend Framework with a PDO defined MySQL database, you would just use:

```
$database=Zend_Db::factory('PDO_MySQL',Array('hostname'=>'localhost','username'=>'x','password'=>'y','dbname'=>'z');
$connectionHandle=$database->getConnection();
$rowsInserted=$connectionHandle->insert('database_name','INSERT INTO x (a,b) VALUES (c,d)');
if ($rowsInserted>0) {
 $autoIncrementValue=$connectionHandle->lastInsertId();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes You can using Shell command `<BR>`
mysql -user -p -h database -e '
SQL STATEMENT 1; 
SQL STATEMENT 2; 
SQL STATEMENT 3; 
.......;
'

[Php / MYSQL Programmer](http://www.snushah.com)

Answer (score 0):

this might do what u want:

```
insert into table1 (Name,Emails) values ('qqq','www');
select max(id) as lastinserted from table1;
```